# Kotlin code convert to Java code Hide Bottom navigation bar?

Tags: java, android, kotlin

**How to Implement code to java**
I'm confused about this line of code `_, destination, _ ->`
I want this code to be possible in java

```
 navController.addOnDestinationChangedListener { _, destination, _ ->
 if(destination.id == R.id.full_screen_destination) {
   toolbar.visibility = View.GONE
   bottomNavigationView.visibility = View.GONE
 } else {
   toolbar.visibility = View.VISIBLE
   bottomNavigationView.visibility = View.VISIBLE
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this page](https://subscription.packtpub.com/book/application-development/9781787123687/5/ch05lvl1sec62/underscore-for-unused-variables), the underbar is used for unused variables in a lambda expression.  So one way to translate this would be to just assign some variable name, then don't use it.

So perhaps something like this (code is untested).

```
 navController.addOnDestinationChangedListener ( (x, destination, y) -> {
 if(destination.id == R.id.full_screen_destination) {
   toolbar.visibility = View.GONE;
   bottomNavigationView.visibility = View.GONE;
 } else {
   toolbar.visibility = View.VISIBLE;
   bottomNavigationView.visibility = View.VISIBLE;
 }
}
)
```

Comment: Thnx  supported : |

Comment: You're missing semicolons.